# Excel SUMIF with OR using cell reference

Tags: excel, reference, cell

I have the following formula

```
= SUM(SUMIF(Sales!A:A,{"Robot","Rocket","Tank"},Sales!B:B))
```

I want to sum the sales volume in column B if column A is any of the following three values: robot, rocket or tank, and the formula works.

However, when I replaces those criteria with cell values,

```
= SUM(SUMIF(Sales!A:A,{"E1","E2","E3"},Sales!B:B))
```

the formula returns 0.

What should I do such that I can use a cell reference instead of an exact value as the criteria?

Thanks.

Comment: to let your formula work, you need to make sure you close it with Ctrl+shift +enter to make it an array formula. Also, you need to reference it as E1:E3.

Comment: Thank you for your solution :)

Answer (score 3):

If the cells (`E1:E3`) are in contiguous range, then you can use:

```
=SUM(SUMIF(Sales!A:A,E1:E3,Sales!B:B))
```

When the cells with conditions are not adjacent (`E1`,`E3`,`E5`), then:

```
=SUM(SUMIF(Sales!A:A,CHOOSE({1;2;3},E1,E3,E5),Sales!B:B))
```

both confirmed with `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`Enter`